# Excel changes typed formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells

Why does excel change cell entrys
Example: 
Initial entry +20+20
Next time I click on cell the contents of cell now is 40
It is not consistent on all cells

Comment: Please clarify. Did you just want to know why it does it? Or are you really asking how to get `+20+20` in the cell without Excel changing it?

Answer (score 1):

If you type `"=20+20"` so this is a simple formula that adds the values that you specify and after executing you will see `40`.

If you type `"+20+20"` is is basically the same like `"=20+20"` and after executing you will see `40`. If you click on the cell you will see `"=20+20"` in formula's control.

If you type `"20+20"` the content will not be changed.